# Conditions in Spring IoC container

Tags: spring

Do I have any known way to inject beans in spring IoC container based on some condition. E.g. I have two beans:

```
<bean id="aaa" class="My"/>
<bean id="bbb" class="My"/>
```

... and want inject it in another bean based on following rule:

*Inject "aaa" if "aaa" isn't null or inject "bbb" in other case*

Thanks

Comment: I have used FactoryBean to solve this problem for myself.

Comment: Can you show us the solution then? Other people might have this problem too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JavaConfig](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) - there you can use java code to implement this logic. I've never used it, but taking an example from the docs:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {
  private @Resource(name="aaa") Aaa aaa;
  private @Resource(name="bbb") Aaa bbb;

  public @Bean TransferService transferService() {
      TransferService service = new TransferServiceImpl();
      if (aaa != null) {
          service.setProperty(aaa);
      } else {
          service.setProperty(bbb);
      }
      return service;
  }
}
```

Another option is to use a `FactoryBean` to encapsulate that logic - the factory bean can lookup a bean in the context, and if found - return it. If not found - lookup another bean.

Comment: ... and then declare `ServiceConfig` itself as a bean in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on spring 3.0 this can be achieved using [SpEL - Expression langauge support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07s04.html).

Comment: Could you give us an example that fits the question, rather than just linking to the documentation?